# How to solve $\log n = n^k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve $\log n = n^k$ where $k > 0$ for $n$. But I fail to do so.
Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I need an expression for $n$.

Comment: you need to use `Lambert W function`

Comment: No solutions for $k>e^{-1}$. One solution $n=e^e$ for $k=e^{-1}$ and two solutions for $k<e^{-1}$ to be found numerically.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log x = x^k$$

$$x^{-k} =y, ~~~ \log y^{-\frac1k} =y^{-1}$$

$$-\frac1k \log y =\frac1y$$

$$y \log y=-k$$

$$z =\log y, ~~~~ z e^z=-k$$

$$z=W(-k),~~~~~~ W=\text{Lambert W function}$$

$$x=y^{-\frac1k}=(\exp z)^{-\frac1k}=(\exp W(-k))^{-\frac1k}$$

Since there is such property : $$\exp W(a)=\frac{a}{W(a)}$$

The above solution can be alternatively written as:

$$x=(\frac{W(-k)}{-k})^{\frac1k}$$